# Toastr doesn't fire when using options

Tags: javascript, user-interface, notifications, toastr

I'm trying to use [toastr js library](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr).

I included toastr.js, toastr.css and toastr-responsive.css
This works:

```
toastr.info("Hello world");
```

But this doesn't work. And I don't get any error in browser console:

```
toastr.options.positionClass = "toast-top-full-width";
toastr.info("Hello world");
```

What would be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Create a fiddle and show me what you are doing.

UPDATE:

You should not link to the raw css and javascript in github. Those are not CDNs, so they are not set up to serve the code. You should pull the code down for your project or use NuGet in Visual Studio.

For example, this works fine if you copy the CSS into the JsFiddle CSS window like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/7Ucj9/10/

And to be complete, here is the minor code change I made ... but it had nothing to do with it

```
$(function () {

    toastr.info("Are you the 6 fingered man?");

    $("#foo1").click(function () {
        alert("test");
    });

    $("#foo2").click(function () {
        toastr.info("Are you the 6 fingered man?");
        console.log("hello");
    });
});
```

Comment: That's my bad. I even couldn't create a working fiddle.. Did I miss something.. http://jsfiddle.net/mavent/7Ucj9/5/